# Can't reach objectForKey - [String : AnyObject] as dictionary

Tags: ios, swift

I am using watch connectivity to receive a message (dictionary generated in objectiveC).
The called delegate function (swift) doesn't want to interpret the received dictionary properly.

ObjectForKey is not found on my dict. What is the reason?
Thanks

```
   func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject]) {
        print("\nWC watch:\n Did receive didReceiveMessage: \(message)")
        var messageDict = message as Dictionary<String, AnyObject> //here I wanted to cast to Dictionary
        let newState = messageDict.objectForKey(WatchManagerMessageMaskStateKey) //but the messageDict does not know objectForKey
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[String : AnyObject]` and `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>` are two notations for exactly the same thing.

`objectForKey` belongs to `NSDictionary`, for the Swift native type use key subscription.
You might cast the result to something more specific.

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject]) {
    print("\nWC watch:\n Did receive didReceiveMessage: \(message)")
    let newState = message[WatchManagerMessageMaskStateKey]
    ...
}
```